# Weight painting gets randomly mirrored to the wrong bone?

Tags: weight-painting

I have a model I rigged to rigify with auto weights. Every now and the when I work, especially working with my mesh in edit mode, I once ive changed a few vertices, or added a few, my weights gets all messed up. The left thigh bone would have weights on both the left and right side of the mesh. And the Right thigh bone would have no weights. Then I have to manually clean up every bone! Any idea why this might happen? Using Blender 3.6. I'm using a smooth corrective modifier too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I faced here was simple. At one point, some vertices of my model did disappear. (No idea how, honestly) After filling in the faces, I hit "symmetrize". This is where I messed up. Based on the axis I selected, I'd lose half of my weight painting, and the other half would be mirrored. It was too late when I realized this, and I couldn't undo. Just leaving this answer here just in case someone else might find it useful. Don't use "symmetrize" when you have a weight painted model. Snap to symmetry might be safe, but I can't test it right now, because I have to fix my weight all over again. If there are other workarounds, feel free to add them to this. Hope this helps someone!